# Analyzing learning curves for facial expression recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a neural network set up in tensorflow (in python) that is operating on the fer2013 dataset (can be found on kaggle). My network architecture is this

```
emotion_model = Sequential()
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
emotion_model.add(Flatten())
emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=28709 // 64,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=7178 // 64)
```

I plotted a learning curve for this algorithm and I got this:
[image: Cost learning curve]

[image: accuracy learning curve]

Now, I am a beginner to machine learning but this divergence in Test vs. Validation data accuracy/cost would seem to point to overfitting of the data. However, I was looking at other people's accuracy levels on the same dataset and found that most people get around 62% accuracy on validation (which is what I have currently) and they usually get about the same for training accuracy. So I'm very surprised that my training data is performing so well (indicating overfitting) and yet my validation accuracy is on par with others implementations. My question is two-fold. First, is there anything wrong with my implementation that may be causing my model to perform so well on training but only average on val (and not really have any room for improvement) or is this just classic overfitting? If it is overfitting, I would appreciate some advice on how to counter this. My dataset is fixed for the most part (I guess I could try to add more data if I need to), I've tried adding some regularization and that harmed performance. Basically, I feel like I'm missing something here. It strikes me as suspicious that my training accuracy is so high and I wanted to check here to make sure I wasn't missing anything before I sink time into trying to correct the overfitting. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite correct: this is the very definition of over-fitting.

- Validation and training losses diverge
- Validation and training accuracies diverge
- Validation loss later increases

In general, we also expect that the validation loss will reach a relative minimum at about the same point -- this defines the convergence point.  Here, it seems that out of the many things the model learns in training, there are still a few useful learnings *after* the divergence point around epoch 8.

The next items to consider are

- What makes you think that you need to train for 50 epochs?  Is it possible that epoch 8 is a reasonable place to halt training?
- Have you checked your data set to ensure that the training set is, indeed, properly representative of the entire data set?
- Consider cross-validation to check the viability of your data splits

Comment: I guess what is confusing me overall is that even though the algorithm is overfitting to the training data, the performance on validation data doesn't decrease, it just stays about the same (roughly). Shouldn't the performance be getting worse on validation data as it overfits to the training data?

Comment: Yes -- in the middle of my answer, I called out that strange increasing validation accuracy.  Without a full example, we can't analyse your accuracy curve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this specific dataset, but, generally speaking, a deep learning model will always converge to best fit the training data given it's strong enough (has enough neurons) to do so.

You can always use dropout layers in between your main layers, which are layers that randomly dropout some pixels in the input to the incoming layer. Just do:

```
emotion_model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_precentage))
```

You could also try using L1 and/or L2 norm, which just adds up the weights of a layer to the final lose, which means that the model can't give a certain feature a large weight, which reduces outfitting. just add a kernel_regularizer argument to layers that containt weights, like:

```
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
    kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l1() ))
```

Comment: I've tried adding kernel regularizers to all my layers and it actually seems to make the validation accuracy decrease which is strange

Comment: Maybe this dataset isn't large enough for the model to generalize. Have you tried data augmentation?

Comment: I haven't tried data augmentation, it's probably a good idea though. I just wanted to make sure it was worth the time first.

Comment: Given the code, you probably did, you can always add more randomness to the image generator. If all of that fails, I'd recommend trying a transfer learning approach. It will be both easy and fun, if you haven't tried it before.

Comment: Oh, about the kernel regulaizer thing. The scale by which the regulaizer is multiplied is an important factor too and might end up damaging the model's behaviour if assigned an arbitrary value.